# Way to look up a CEO's salary at particular companies?

Tags: business

Does anyone know a good resource I can use to search for companies and then find out the salaries of it's CEO? I'm trying to find out what CEOs at small healthcare services and technology companies in Dallas make.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your goal in doing this research?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because research on CEO's salary has nothing to do with navigating TWP.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere IMO that is so razor thin its almost non existent.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/faq-addendum-typical-salary-hourly-rates-are-off-topic

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The user **can** update the question after it's closed, right?

Answer (score 7):

> Does anyone know a good resource I can use to search for companies and
>   then find out the salary of it's CEO?

A good Google search can determine the names of such companies.

Compensation of executives for publicly-traded companies are listed at Morningstar.com

- Search for and find the company.
- Click the stock ticker.
- Select the Executives tab.

Comment: Voting for this because even though the question is clearly off topic, it does give the OP an answer that works.

Answer (score 2):

Google maybe.  Seriously, if it is a public company then they must file with the SEC in the US.  If you are generically looking for comparison purposes that will require leg work to know the companies specifically rather than generally.

Most salary sites like Glassdoor.com use crowdsourced data and I just don't see most CEOs volunteering that information.

So back to my opening statement.  Just google the name of the company and CEO salary and if it is publicly available you should get plenty of links.  If it is not, then you really have no way of knowing.

For example, searching for the CEO Salary for Aetna, google gives it to you right in the search results.

On the other hand, searching for private company Cook Medical, and you find very little.  BTW, the CEO is Carl Cook,#65 on the Forbes 400 in 2017.  No mention of Salary anywhere, but he does own the company his father founded.

Answer (score 1):

Public companies are easy so I assume you are asking about a private company. You can't get the specific salary of a private individual without having someone who knows the answer tell you. If you want to know what range a CEO in a given industry and location should get paid then here are a few ideas.

1. Ask someone who would know. People who you could ask are c-level executives at such companies or members of the board at such companies.
2. If you are looking to get such a job its worth consulting with a executive talent search firm to get their advice on the market. This could be tricky as they will want to be the agent of record when you get haired.
3. Companies such as Radford Surveys and Culpepper provide sell detailed anonymized compensation data for many roles, industries and market places.

Keep in mind that a large proportion of a CEO compensation may be based on company performance therefore salary numbers may not be very meaningful on their own and total compensation can vary a lot. Also, many CEOs of privately held companies may also own a significant stake in the company and therefore may only pay themselves a modest salary to live on.